# R LDAvis defining documents for each topic

Tags: r, text-mining, lda, topic-modeling

This is a question about LDA and the application LDAvis in R. As this is my first time using this package I would appreciate any help that could help my research.

I want to be able to view the documents that have been defined by each topic based on probability. I am using survey data and I am looking at the comment section and have defined each of them as documents.

I am going to use the example "A topic model for movie reviews" by cpsievert, as this is very similar to my code. The full code can be found in the following link: Visit

http://cpsievert.github.io/LDAvis/reviews/reviews.html

I have got to the stage of fitting the model using the LDA model based on the following code:

```
set.seed(123)
fit <- lda.collapsed.gibbs.sampler(documents = documents, K = K, vocab = vocab, 
                               num.iterations = G, alpha = alpha, 
                               eta = eta, initial = NULL, burnin = 0,
                               compute.log.likelihood = TRUE)
```

And then used the LDAvis to create the interactive html, with the following code:

```
json <- createJSON(phi = MovieReviews$phi, 
               theta = MovieReviews$theta, 
               doc.length = MovieReviews$doc.length, 
               vocab = MovieReviews$vocab, 
               term.frequency = MovieReviews$term.frequency)
```

Now based on the interactive html I have defined the topic based on the frequency terms. There is an example of this on Movie Reviews, which can be found with following link:

http://cpsievert.github.io/LDAvis/reviews/vis/#topic=7&lambda=0.6&term=

This topic can be defined as comedies for Movie Reviews.

So if in this example "topic7" is known as comedies, how can you view the reviews, which are most probable to be defined by this topic?

I would like to know, how would I define documents based on topic7 and then be able to view them, say using:

```
View(MovieReviwes$Topic7)
```

I apologise if this question is broad and long, but if someone could answer it by using the example I have given in the link, this would help greatly. Thanks in advance.

Comment: are you looking to view them outside of the HTML interface?

Comment: Yes if I could view it in R as what documents are with in the topic.

Comment: so topic7 would filter out documents  `[7] ....funny..... jokes...` and `[1009] ......woody....hilarious` and so on

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you may not fully understand what lda's do and how they work. The lda model will generate a list of *k* topics, and then tell you which words were assigned to which topics and their respective probabilities for being assigned to each of the various topics. It sounds like what you're really trying to do is perform document/topic classification rather than word/topic classification, and if that's the case then the `lda` package isn't going to suit your needs.

If you wanted a *really* dirty method of document classification based on the `lda` object I guess you could just return the name of the topic with the greatest number of words assigned to it for each document, though I'd imagine that you'd run into issues if there were ties (the probability of ties increases as *k* increases and the number of documents increases).

EDIT: The quick and dirty way as requested:

```
sums <- fit$document_sums
sums <- t(sums)
sums <- as.data.frame(sums)
topics <- colnames(sums)[max.col(sums,ties.method="first")]
topics <- t(topics)
sums$topics <- topics
```

Comment: What I want to do is compare topics to another variable, so if it is a word/topic classification that is ok. My data set is mobile/cell phone survey data where comments are left and they are normally only a couple of sentences in text, I would like to compare this to 1-5 star rating, which is the overall satisfaction. So I know what the topics are based on the words that are used from LDAvis html, but how can extract that topic and compare it to the variable. Is this possible? Thanks for you help in advance.

Comment: @Ace, do you need topic word counts? probabilities? And do you need them in long (rows = documents, cols = topics) or wide (just the opposite) format?

Comment: I think this is the best way to describe it, if I have csv file with two columns, one has Movie reviews and another has 1-5 star rating. I would like to know how many stars or if possible the probability that it will have 1 star based on the topic. Like topic7 is comedy and how many would have a 1star rating if it is a comedy (or maybe show this is a graph). In terms of topic word counts I know the `fit$topics` would give me the word count for each document. Again thanks for the help

Comment: @Ace, it still sounds like you're looking to classify movie reviews into singular topics (genres) and not analyze the words/topic classifications of individual words within the reviews. For this you will need to perform document classification as I explained in my original answer.

Comment: What would you suggest is the best way to do a document classification on survey data from the comment section. Preferably using something R.

Comment: Take a look at RTextTools. It's a pretty easy package to work with and should get you what you need. [Here](http://www.journal.r-project.org/archive/2013-1/collingwood-jurka-boydstun-etal.pdf) is a getting started guide.

Comment: I will try this, just to clarify this, is there no way to classify each or some document/reviews and the probability that they belong to a topic? Like review 108 is likely to belong to topic 7. Thanks

Comment: You could try the max topic count idea I mentioned, but it'd be far from perfect.

Comment: Ok Thanks, if I were to approach this with max topic count, how would I code this using the movie reviews example, perhaps you could do this in the form of answer rather than a comment. Sorry about the amount of comments, I would use chat but I don't have enough reputation yet.

Comment: @Ace - edited my answer to provide you with one way to do it.